# In Excel VBA read entire sheet (by selection) into python style list of lists

Tags: excel, vba

I want to put whatever values are in an excel sheet into a list of lists in visual basic, with each sublist being an entire row. then please tell me how to print that array in the debug window, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what a "list of lists" looks like, but you can just read the data into an array and use it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
        v = .Value
        Debug.Print "v is dimensioned as (" & LBound(v, 1) & " To " & UBound(v, 1) & ", " & _
                                              LBound(v, 2) & " To " & UBound(v, 2) & ")"
        For r = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
            For c = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
                Debug.Print "Row " & r & ", Col " & c & ":" & v(r, c)
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The first dimension of the array represents rows, the second dimension represents columns.

Comment: which variable contains the two dimensional array version of the sheet?

Comment: so [[row1 cell1, row1 cell2], [row2 cell1, row2 cell2]]

Comment: @new_to_coding `v` is the array.  `v(1,1)` is row 1 column 1, `v(1,2)` is row 1 column 2, `v(2,1)` is row 2 column 1, `v(2,2)` is row 2 column 2, etc.  So every position x of `v(1,x)` is a cell in row 1.  Also every position x of `v(x,1)` is a cell in column 1.